# How can I create a background process in electron that takes screenshot of the entire desktop?

Tags: angular, electron, background-process

I am creating a Desktop application with angular2 and electron which take screenshots of the entire desktop and save it in my PC to a given path.The code for taking screenshots are written in the app.component.ts but I have to do this task as a background process in electron.I have read about the background process but I am not sure how to actually implement this in electron as a background process.Can someone please help me with this? Here is my code:

`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { desktopCapturer, remote, dialog, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import { writeFile} from 'fs';`

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
```

})

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
this.myScreen();

}

myScreen()
{
    let n = <any>navigator;
    electron.desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'], thumbnailSize: { width: 100, height: 50 } }, (error, sources) => {
        console.log(sources);
        if (error) throw error;
        for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
            console.log(sources[i]);
                n.webkitGetUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                            chromeMediaSourceId: sources[i].id,
                            minWidth: 1280,
                            maxWidth: 1280,
                            minHeight: 720,
                            maxHeight: 720
                        }
                    }
                }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
                return;
            // }
        }

    });

    function gotStream(stream) {

        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
        console.log("Stream");
        var video = document.createElement('video');

        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = this.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = this.videoHeight;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

            var dot=".";
            console.log("helo1");
            console.warn("helo1")
            var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
            var ext = url.split(';')[0].match(/jpeg|png|gif/)[0];
            var data1 = url.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            console.warn("inside loader");

            fs.writeFile('C:/Users/user/Downloads/image'+randomnumber+dot+ext,data1,'base64',function (err) {
                console.warn("fs");
                if (err) {
                    alert("An error ocurred creating the file " + err.message)
                }
            });

           }, false);

        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();


  }

    function addImage(image) {
        const snap = document.createElement("img");
        snap.src = image.toDataURL();
        document.body.appendChild(snap);
    }

    function getUserMediaError(e) {
        console.log('getUserMediaError');
    }

     var timeId= setInterval(this.myScreen,3000);
}
```

}

Comment: Hello,
Did you find any solution for this question?
As I am also looking for same stuff.

Comment: @KunalKakkad I have not find the exact solution but I took help from this project [link](https://github.com/smith-kyle/electron-background-process-app)

Comment: ok thanks. Will check it.

Comment: Hi.. super late to the party.. has anyone tried [Electron Bg](https://github.com/johnhaley81/electron-background-task-app) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a two approaches for running non-blocking background tasks:

- Using web workers - it's the "cleanest" approach. Unfortunately, workers can't access the Node JS capabilities.
- Using a hidden browser window - this seems like a hack, but actually works quite well. You can communicate between the main app and background windows via electron's RPC.